# DB::update laravel 5 raw query

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel, eloquent

I intend to use laravel db update which equivalent to sql.

```
update users set username = "admin", status = "active" where user_id = 1
```

This is the query I test to run. Any wrong?

```
$username = "admin";
$status = "active";

DB::update('update users set username = '  .$username. ',
status = '.$status.'  where user_id = ?' ,['1']);
```

Answer (score 22):

You should update your query like :

**Eloquent Query:**

```
User::where('user_id',1)->update(array(
                         'username'=>$username,
));
```

**Fluent Query:**

```
DB::table('users')->where('user_id',1)->update(array(
                                 'username'=>$username,
));
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: When it comes to multiple conditions in where clause it is modified as                                              `DB::table('table')->where([ ['column1','=',val1'],['column2','=','val2']])->update(['UpdateColunn'=>'updateValue']);`

Answer (score 14):

The correct query would be

```
DB::update('update users set username = ? , status = ? where user_id = ?', ["admin" , "active" , 1]);
```

OR

```
User::where('user_id', 1)->update( array('username'=>'admin', 'status'=>'active') );
```

Where "User" is the model name of "users" table.

Comment: What will be the result of the first RAW `DB::update` method?

Comment: It returns number of rows changed; 0 if no row changed

Answer (score 7):

The better way to do that with laravel query builder is:

```
DB::table('users')
    ->where('user_id', 1)
    ->update(['username' => $username, 'status' => $status]);
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using raw query , it can be done as

update users set username = "admin", status = "active" where user_id = 1

```
DB::table('users')
->where('user_id',1)
->update(['username'=>'admin','status'=>'active']);
```

OR

```
$username = "admin";
$status = "active";

DB::update(DB::RAW('update users set username = '  .$username. ',
status = '.$status.'  where user_id = ?' ,['1']));
```

Answer (score -1):

The correct ways to Call **DB::update** you need something like this

```
      $username = "admin";
      $status = "active";
      DB::update('update users set username = ? , status = ? where user_id = ?', [$username , $status , 1]);
```

This should return number of rows affected